# MapRoute() not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to redirect `Company/Careers/OpenPosition` to `Company/OpenPosition`. Why the following MapRoute() call is not working?

Thanks.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Company", // Route name
            "Careers/OpenPosition/{action}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Company", action = "OpenPosition" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: Im guessing it needs to be like follows:
routes.MapRoute(
            "Company", // Route name
            "Company/Careers/OpenPosition/",
            new { controller = "Company", action = "OpenPosition" }
        );
or
routes.MapRoute(
            "Company", // Route name
            "Company/Careers/OpenPosition/{customVariable}",
            new { controller = "Company", action = "OpenPosition" }
        );

Comment: You are right, please add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like follows:

```
routes.MapRoute( "Company", // Route name 
"Company/Careers/OpenPosition/",
 new { controller = "Company", action = "OpenPosition" } );
```

or

```
routes.MapRoute( "Company", // Route name
"Company/Careers/OpenPosition/{customVariable}",
     new { controller = "Company", action = "OpenPosition" } );
```

Comment: now I have this side effect: if I browse `Company/Careers` I get the following `Company/Careers/OpenPosition/Careers`. Do you know why? Can it be avoided? Thanks.

Comment: so change your route to this : `routes.MapRoute( "Company", // Route name 
"Company/Careers/{action}/",
 new { controller = "Company", action = "OpenPosition" } );`

Comment: @abenci did it helped you?

Comment: Here you go: `routes.MapRoute("Company", "Company/Careers/{action}/", new {controller = "Company", action = "OpenPosition"});`

Answer (score 0):

like follows:

```
routes.MapRoute( "Company", // Route name 
"Company/Careers/OpenPosition/",
    new { controller = "Company", action = "OpenPosition" } );
```

or

```
routes.MapRoute( "Company", // Route name
 "Company/Careers/OpenPosition/{customVariable}",
    new { controller = "Company", action = "OpenPosition" } );
```